# Change ICN contentViewer's tab title in split pane mode?

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

I need to change the "title" for each document shown in ICN Viewer, dynamically, at runtime.  I'll read the new viewer tab title from the document properties.

Environment: ICN 2.0.3 CM8.5 WAS 8.5.5

Code so far:

1. I found a PARTIAL solution by hooking "ecm.model.desktop, onChange":

   ```
    aspect.after(ecm.model.desktop, 'onChange', function() {
       var contentViewer = dijit.byId('contentViewer');
       if (contentViewer) {
          var viewerTabTitleDef = new ViewerTabTitleDef ();
          contentViewer.mainTabContainer.getChildren().forEach(function(child) {
             viewerTabTitleDef.changeTitle(viewerTabTitleDef.self,
                child.controlButton, child.contentViewerPane.viewerItem.item);
          });
          ...
   ```
2. I was able to extend this for subsequent documents opened in the same viewer, and optimized by "removing()" the handler after this initial call. Here is the complete code:

   ```
    var kill = aspect.after(ecm.model.desktop, 'onChange', function() {

       var contentViewer = dijit.byId('contentViewer');
       // "contentViewer" will be "unknown" unless viewer invoked
       console.log('onChange: contentViewer', contentViewer);  

       if (contentViewer) {
          console.log("new ViewerTabTitleDef()...");
          kill.remove();
          var viewerTabTitleDef = new ViewerTabTitleDef ();
          contentViewer.mainTabContainer.getChildren().forEach(function(child) {
              // For initially opened tabs
              console.log('initially opened: child', child);
              viewerTabTitleDef.changeTitle(viewerTabTitleDef.self, child.controlButton, child.contentViewerPane.viewerItem.item);
          });
          aspect.after(contentViewer.mainTabContainer, 'addChild', function(child) {
              // For tabs added after the viewer was opened
              console.log('subsequently opened: child', child);
              viewerTabTitleDef.changeTitle(viewerTabTitleDef, child.controlButton, child.contentViewerPane.viewerItem.item);
          }, true);
       } // end if contentViewer

    });  // end aspect.after(onChange desktop)
   ```
3. Current problem: how can I change the label for a split tab (either vertical or horizontal)?

So far, I have *NOT* been able to find any event for any ICN/ECM widget or object variable that I can trigger on.

Comment: The edit here is a good one: answers go in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to show a different tab-title (instead of the document title) in the navigator viewer whenever a doc is opened.

How about this?

Every document you open in the viewer is wrapped in a `ecm.widget.viewer.model.ViewerItem` which exposes the `getHtmlName` that returns the name used in the tab.

Your solution would be to implement your own `getHtmlName`.

Unfortunately though, the `ViewerItem` is constructed in the `ecm.widget.viewer.ContentViewer#_open` and then passed to the `ecm.widget.viewer.ContentViewer#_openTab`. So you'll either violate best practice by mingling with IBM private methods, or you'll go for a generic approach and just replace the `ecm.widget.viewer.model.ViewerItem.prototype.getHtmlName`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion: thank you.  I'll let you know how it goes; I'll be sure to "accept" if it works!

Comment: Good luck! You could start with this arbitrary example that presents the document id as title: `require(["ecm/widget/viewer/model/ViewerItem"],function(ContentViewer){
ContentViewer.prototype.getHtmlName=function (){
return this.item.id;
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

*(I am posting the answer on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer section)*.

Many thanks to Ivo Jonker, for his suggestion to modify the widget prototype's
"getHtmlName()" method.  It worked!

Specifically:

1. I'm invoking this code from an ICN plugin.  I set event handlers in my plugin's base .js file, but it actually gets invoked in the new, separate viewer window.
2. The original prototype looked like this:

   ```
    getHtmlName: function() {
        var methodName = "getHtmlName";
        this.logEntry(methodName);

        var displayName = this.item.getDisplayValue("{NAME}");
        if (displayName == "") {
            displayName = this.item.name;
        }

        var htmlName = entities.encode(displayName);
        this.logExit(methodName);
        return htmlName;
    },
   ```
3. Per Ivo's suggestion, I overrode the prototype method like this:

   ```
        myPluginDojo.viewerTabTitleDef = viewerTabTitleDef;
        ...
        ecm.widget.viewer.model.ViewerItem.prototype.getHtmlName = function () {
            console.log("NEW getHtmlName()...");
            var displayName = myPluginDojo.viewerTabTitleDef.getTitle(this.item);
            return displayName;
        };
   ```

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing) you need to blockquote.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean @starball - since the material comes from the question author, and it was re-posted by me, then it needs to be `>` quoted in its entirety. I don't agree with that - the idea here is that the first line indicates that the whole post can be taken to be in the question author's voice.

Comment: (If they were to repost it themselves I'd be happy to delete the CW copy, but unfortunately the question author is keen to oppose a number of community standards, and is not minded to collaborate to such a degree).